# Java DecimalFormat shows different results for float and double

Tags: java, floating-point, double, decimalformat

why is the result different?
If i use float it get ,675 and if i use double i get ,674... isnt that weird?

```
float f = 12345.6745;
double d = 12345.6745;

Locale l = Locale.forLanguageTag("es-ES");
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(l);
print(df.format(f));
>> 12.345,675

l = Locale.forLanguageTag("es-ES");
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(l);
print(df.format(d));
>> 12.345,674
```

Thanks

Comment: Because `float` and `double` are not the same. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If i use float it get ,675 and if i use double i get ,674... isnt that weird?

Not particularly. You're formatting different values. In particular, assuming you actually change your code so that it will *compile* (with an `f` suffix for the float), even though you're *specifying* 9 digits, `float` will only reliably represent 7.

Neither of the numbers is *exactly* 12345.6745. In fact, the exact values are:

```
f = 12345.6748046875
d = 12345.674499999999170540831983089447021484375
```

Look at those and it's obvious why the third decimal place is 5 for `f` and 4 for `d`.

If you want to preserve decimal digits, you should be considering using [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have a representation error. This is more obvious when you have an overflow.

```
long l = 1234567890123456789L;
double d = l;
float f = l;
int i = (int) l;
short s = (short) l;
char ch = (char) l;
byte b = (byte) l;
System.out.println("l= " + l + " in hex " + Long.toHexString(l));
System.out.println("d= " + d);
System.out.println("f= " + f);
System.out.println("i= " + i + " in hex " + Integer.toHexString(i));
System.out.println("s= " + s + " in hex " + Integer.toHexString(s & 0xFFFF));
System.out.println("(int) ch= " + (int) ch +  " in hex " + Integer.toHexString(ch));
System.out.println("b= " + b +  " in hex " + Integer.toHexString(b));
```

prints

```
l= 1234567890123456789 in hex 112210f47de98115
d= 1.23456789012345677E18
f= 1.23456794E18
i= 2112454933 in hex 7de98115
s= -32491 in hex 8115
(int) ch= 33045 in hex 8115
b= 21 in hex 15
```

Only `long` can represent this value without error (plus BigInteger and BigDecimal) All other data types have different errors. `float` and `double` represent the top bits accurately whereas `int`, `short`, `char` and `byte` represent the lowest bits accurately.